# How to Calculate Running balance in sql Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to Calculate ruining Balance in Sql Server 2008.
i am using following query working perfectly in sql server 2012 but not in sql server 2008.

```
SELECT empid, tentryno, glcode, descript, linenarrat, ttype, amount, tapplid, ftype, mentryno, mthttype, entrydate, ref, refdate, remarks, narrat, postflag, mapplid, mtype, post, acctheadcode, accthead, subacctheadcode, subaccthead
       , CASE 
        WHEN ttype = 'D'
            THEN amount
        ELSE 0.00
        END AS Debit, CASE 
        WHEN ttype = 'C'
            THEN amount
        ELSE 0.00
        END AS Credit, SUM(CASE 
            WHEN ttype = 'D'
                THEN amount
            ELSE amount * - 1
            END) OVER (
        PARTITION BY glcode ORDER BY tseqid
        ) AS balance, STATUS, receid, system.title, dbo.system.address, dbo.system.phone1, dbo.system.phone2, dbo.system.fax, dbo.system.signimage, dbo.system.logo
FROM CreditDebitDetails
CROSS JOIN system
WHERE STATUS != 0
```

Comment: You can try to format your query if you want someone to help you. Also this question is not related directly to C#.

Comment: _ruining Balance_ really ? Or 'running' balance? Put a little more effort into a question here, please! Do you really expect us to scroll over all that distance?

Comment: `;WITH cte
  AS (
  <<your query>>
  )
SELECT *
FROM   cte a
  CROSS apply (SELECT Sum(CASE
         WHEN ttype = 'D' THEN amount
         ELSE amount * -1
        END) AS balance
     FROM   cte b
     WHERE  a.glcode = b.glcode
       AND a.tseqid >= b.tseqid) cs`

Comment: You are right Prdp... my bad :)

Comment: thanx sir. i have use your query successfully run on sql server 2008.